# Grade Mapping Using Bisect

Tags: python-3.x

```
from bisect import bisect

grades = "FEDCBA"
breakpoints = [30, 44, 66, 75, 85]  

def grade(total):
    return grades[bisect(breakpoints, total)]

print(grade(66))
print(list(map(grade, [33, 99, 77, 44, 12, 88])))

'''
C
['E', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'F', 'A']

[Program finished]'''
```

Not my program. Imported from enki.
Bisect module provides support for maintaining a list in sorted order without having to sort the list after each insertion. 
So, when we call `grade(66)`. It passes 66 to the grade function which returns `C`, How?
The second print statement is even more confusing.
It is mapping function grade with a List.
If I try to print, `print (grades[bisect(breakpoints, grades)])`, 
I get Err,

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code produced the correct results for the data you fed it!

The breakpoint list `[30, 44, 66, 75, 85]` bisects the letter string `"FEDCBA"` as follows:

```
If         grade < 30 then F 
If   30 <= grade < 44 then E  
If   44 <= grade < 66 then D
If   66 <= grade < 75 then C 
If   75 <= grade < 85 then B
If   85 <= grade      then A
```

Therefore `print(grade(66))` correctly resulted in an output of `C`.

Similarly, your `print(list(map(grade, [33, 99, 77, 44, 12, 88])))` correctly resulted in an output of `['E', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'F', 'A']`.

Now regarding your getting `TypeError` because of `print (grades[bisect(breakpoints, grades)])`, it just looks like you meant to do `grades[bisect(breakpoints, total)]` instead.  Notice `total` instead of `grades` as the second argument to `bisect()`.

Here's another version of the working code which puts all the variables at the top so you can change them easier for testing:

```
data_list = [33, 99, 77, 44, 12, 88]
grade_string = 'FEDCBA'
breakpoint_list = [30, 44, 66, 75, 85]
def grade(total, breakpoints=breakpoint_list, grades=grade_string):
    i = bisect(breakpoints, total)
    return grades[i]

print([grade(total) for total in data_list])
```

The output is:

```
['E', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'F', 'A']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from bisect import bisect

grades = "FEDCBA"
breakpoints = [95, 44, 66, 75, 85]  


def grade(total):
    i = bisect(breakpoints, total)
    return grades[i]

print("Original Data:", [grade(total) for total in breakpoints ])
print("Data within print statement:",list(map(grade, [33, 99, 77, 44, 12, 88])))
```

Thanks Scott, 
    Original Data: ['A', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A']
    Data within print statement: ['F', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'F', 'A']
I was able to produce the output I wanted for learning purpose